# How to match the start and end of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, space

I try to match space at the start and the end of string, I tried many regexes but nothing worked, this is my basic regex:

```
^\s\s$
```

Any help or hint please? I would like to not give me the answer directly, just useful hints will be useful.

Comment: do you need to match both, or optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex will match things like 2 spaces, because that's what your regex says:

> start of string, whitespace, whitespace, end of string

To match spaces both at the start and at the end, you need to use the `|` to mean "or". If the whitespace is either at the start or the end, we match it:

```
^\s|\s$
```

If you want to match multiple spaces:

```
^\s+|\s+$
```